# php pdo query range select with value "Above"

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM salary_table WHERE "
. "(cast(min_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) <= :name AND :name <= cast(max_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) OR cast(min_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) <= :name AND LOWER(max_compensation) = 'above' OR :name <= cast(max_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) AND LOWER(min_compensation) = 'below') AND date_deleted IS NULL"); //AND date_deleted IS NULL
$stmt->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Database Record:

```
Min : 1000000
Max : Above
```

Search Parameter:

"Above"

This scenario should query the record with the max value above. But I am getting the lowest value because when name is applied with `Floatval()` it becomes `0` so what i did is do :

```
$name = (floatval($_POST['name']) > 0) ? floatval($_POST['name']) : $_POST['name'];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM salary_table WHERE "
. "( (LOWER(max_compensation) = :name OR LOWER(min_compensation) = :name) OR (cast(min_compensation as decimal(10, 6)) <= :name AND :name <= cast(max_compensation as decimal(10, 6)))) AND date_deleted IS NULL"); //AND date_deleted IS NULL
$stmt->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

`FYI`

When I echo `$name` it outputs:

```
Above
```

But still I am getting the record where the minimum is `0`.

[image]

The image above is the record in my database. When I search with `Above` **I should get the second record instead I am getting the first**

> How to deal with this range string comparison.

Comment: Provide some sample data and your expected result from your sample data

Comment: @Viki888 added an image hope this will make it easy for understading my problem

Comment: I can't follow your question. Pls provide sample data and expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: sample data is above on image those are data in database now. scenario is when i select record in database where parameter is "above" **i should get the second record because max is equal to "above"** @Shadow i hope it is clear.

Comment: Just replace below with 0 (or -1) and above with the max value of your chosen numeric field. You are just complicating your own life with this design.

Comment: actually in below no problem because `Floatval()` will turn it to zero. my problem is with above i dont know how much will be max so i am doing it this way. @Shadow

Comment: With the current design you cannot use a numeric data type to store numeric values, so all queries on these fields will involve a type conversion -> they will run slower and will consume more resources. Store the values in a numeric field that has a capacity to store even high numbers and make max the highest possible number that this numeric field can hold. Or at least use `null` in place of a word.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132677/discussion-between-pekka-and-shadow).